# How to convert a json formatted data in one of the column in python dataframe to multiple separate rows

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with columns as resource_name, version_id, create_time, update_time, eval_metrics and eval_values. One of the record has "confidenceMetrics" as  the value for column eval_metrics. The eval_values for this record is like {'falsepositiverate' : 1.0, 'falsepositivecount' : 0.9, 'truepositivecount' : 0.0767, 'precisionAt1' : 0.5, 'precision' : 0.5, 'f1score' : 0.667, 'recall' : 0.3}. The eval_Value is not in a json format it doesn't have double quotes as a typical json format would. Can the eval_values be converted and split the falsepositiverate, falsepositivecount, truepositivecount, precisionAt1, precision, f1score, recall  into separate rows of their own with resource_name, version_id, create_time, update_time columns remaining same.

I used the following code:

```
# convert eval_Values to a JSON string
df['eval_Values'] = df['eval_Values'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x))

# expand eval_Values into separate rows
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['eval_Values'], axis=1), df['eval_Values'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

# melt the falsepositiverate, falsepositivecount, truepositivecount, precisionAt1, precision, f1score, recall
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['resource_name', 'version_id', 'create_time', 'update_time', 'EvaluationMetrics'], value_vars=['falsepositiverate', 'falsepositivecount', 'truepositivecount', 'precisionAt1', 'precision', 'f1score', 'recall'], var_name='metric', value_name='value')

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

It throws an error `KeyError: The following 'value_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: [falsepositiverate, falsepositivecount, truepositivecount, precisionAt1, precision, f1score, recall]`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1/241036727.py in <module>
----> 1 test_get_model_evaluation('employee_attrition_test_v3')

/tmp/ipykernel_1/3746496771.py in test_get_model_evaluation(modelname)
     91 
     92     # melt the falsepositive, falseNegative, and f1Score columns into rows
---> 93     df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['resource_name', 'version_id', 'create_time', 'update_time', 'evaluation_metrics'], value_vars=['falsePositiveRate', 'falsePositiveCount','truePositiveCount','precisionAt1', 'precision', 'f1Score', 'recallAt1', 'f1ScoreAt1', 'confusionMatrix', 'confidenceThreshold', 'falsePositiveRateAt1', 'recall'], var_name='metric', value_name='value')
     94 
     95 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py in melt(frame, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level, ignore_index)
    100             if not missing.empty:
    101                 raise KeyError(
--> 102                     "The following 'value_vars' are not present in "
    103                     f"the DataFrame: {list(missing)}"
    104                 )

KeyError: "The following 'value_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['confidenceThreshold', 'confusionMatrix', 'f1Score', 'f1ScoreAt1', 'falsePositiveCount', 'falsePositiveRate', 'falsePositiveRateAt1', 'precision', 'precisionAt1', 'recall', 'recallAt1', 'truePositiveCount']"
```

Please see how the expected output is

[image]

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher sure. I have added the full traceback

Comment: If such a string only appears in a single or a few rows, most of the work can be done in Python. To convert such a not-really-JSON to a Python dict, there is `ast.literal_eval`. Then the items of the dict can be processed one by one to create new rows or just be converted to a dataframe, the repeating data of the original row added and the new data frame appended to or inserted into the original one.